# Sort list of list containing string and int

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

how i can sort a list of list containing string and int..

```py
user_list = [
    ['Jo Marat', 3],
    ['titi toto', 3],
    ['Mr DoD', 6],
    ['Zebrra Benda', 1]
]
```

sorted :

```py
sorted_list = [
    ['Mr DoD', 6],
    ['Jo Marat', 3],
    ['titi toto', 3],
    ['Zebrra Benda', 1]
]
```

i try insertion algorithm but I dont' know how i can adapt this algo to my need...

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you tried calling `.sort()` on the list, or passing it to `sorted()`? You can provide a `key` function that allows you to select a specific part of the elements.

Comment: `sorted(user_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`